# NCover code coverage result for deliberately failing tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage, ncover

I have a couple of unit test helper extension methods, such as, `IsNotEmpty(this string str)` for which I have also written unit tests. The basic structure of these tests is that I have one test that verifies that the extension method passes and returns the expected result on a "good" input, and one that verifies that a fail exception is thrown on "bad" input. For example, the fail tests for the above method might look like this:

```
[TestMethod, Fails]
public void IsNotEmpty_Fails_On_Empty_String()
{
    "".IsNotEmpty();
}
```

where `Fails` is an attribute I wrote myself - basically a proxy for `[ExpectedException(typeof(AssertFailedException))]`. So I'm *explicitly expecting* an exception to be thrown on the only line in the above test, and thus, I'm *not* expecting the method to run all the way.

But when I right-click my solution, select "Test with->NCover", I get less than 100% code coverage* on all methods like the above one, with the ending brace highlighted red.

**Why does NCover complain about my *test* method not finishing, when I've said that it won't?**

**) For all those of you who will reply that 100% code coverage is not necessary: No, I'm not particularily worried about maintaining a 100% code coverage at all costs. However, in these cases methods that* do *matter show up as not covered in the list, and I have to go all the way into the tree to see that it's just them.* That's *the issue I'm trying to get at here - not 100% code coverage in general.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running a debug build? That's probably the issue. NCover works off of the debugging breakpoints, and Microsoft adds one to the closing bracket of each method so it can step there before leaving the method. Running in release mode should take care of those closing brackets for you.

Comment: Good catch! Changing the build configration to Release fixed it =)

Comment: I came across the same issue with dotCover.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about 100% code coverage.  Just get as close as you reasonably can.

Attaining 100% code coverage is a waste of time.

All that matters is that you are confident in your tests covering the code that needs to be covered.

You can have a solid set of tests that only cover 70% of your code.

Your best tests likely only cover a few lines, but they are the ones that will prevent most of the bugs.  They are the 'edge case tests'.  The ones that without them, the other tests are useless.  Your entire test suite is useless, as they are the cases that test the mistakes that would typically keep getting reintroduced into code base if they didn't exist.

Comment: I'm not *in general* worried about 100% code coverage, but it's annoying to see all these red (or ignored - yes, I know about that option) things in the list just because NCover doesn't run past the last brace of a test method.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken, yea, that is annoying, that's why I don't check my code coverage anymore.  I try to follow TDD, knowing that all my code will be covered, regardless of what the tools report.

Comment: If you are doing TDD, you can't write any code before you have written a test, so you should have 100% code coverage - so your tools should be reporting 100% - otherwise you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Sohnee, in theory, yes, in practice, you never have 100% code coverage.  There is often a lot of auto-generated code.  Not to mention, a lot of your tests, will be testing mocks and stubs, not always the actual implementation.

Comment: If you are mocking something, it is normally because that "something" has its own unit tests. I can't see any reason for sub-100% coverage.

Comment: @Sohnee, the point is that TDD isn't about getting 100% code coverage.  It's about producing highly tested, quality code.  Having near 100% code coverage is a side-effect.  When I add a service reference to a webservice, I get a lot of generated code added to my app...I'm not going to spend a day writing test cases for it all, there is no need.  I only need to write tests for the calls I make to that code.  Thus, I won't have 100% code coverage.  But, I still have quality, highly tested and highly covered code that I am confident in.  And that is the point.

Comment: But you can exclude auto generated code from the metrics, so why ignore what the tools report? Bob Martin and Phil Haack had this discussion a few weeks back.